# Is there a ASP.NET web site administration tool in IIS?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, iis

I am using asp.net web site administration tool to manage the different roles in my project (currently Customer and Administrator). During the development, in vs 2008, its very easy to manage the roles. (Project -> Asp.Net configuration). How do I manage my roles and users when the system is deployed (IIS)? Is it possible to run a "asp.net web administration tool-services" on IIS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Supposedly, developers are intended to admin the site using the visual studio web site administration tool.  There is no out-of-the-box web interface to front-end that stuff.

Answer (score 13):

This article describes how to create one, including the code that you can directly embed in your website:

https://web.archive.org/web/20210510020726/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/053007-1.aspx

This article describes how you can run the ASP.NET configuration website administration tool on IIS:
http://blogs.msdn.com/rahulso/archive/2006/03/09/547402.aspx

Update: here's a very basic example in MVC3/Razor:
http://www.mikepope.com/blog/DisplayBlog.aspx?permalink=2240#Create_a_page_to_manage_roles

Comment: Good post. these are the two articles I have used. The 4guys from rolla code is much better because you can customize and configure it more succinctly.

Comment: Yeah, the example I have on the blog is part of a post on how to get security implemented using absolutely as little code as possible. Definitely not any aspirations there to show production-quality anything. :-)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a SQL Server instance, rather than the mapped database file in APP_DATA you can use the ASP.Net configuration tool by temporarily changing the Connection String for the database to point to your live database rather than the local one - this will enable you to edit the roles/users etc.

However, it's one of those areas where you should probably look at writing/finding a tool to edit/manage these properly.

Answer (score 1):

you can create an application in IIS, you just know that direction of web administration tools (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles)

the other point that you should now is that you need two parameter in the URL.

AS an example:
http://localhost/PMIS-Security/default.aspx?applicationPhysicalPath=C:\PMIS&applicationUrl=/PMIS

applicationPhysicalPath=C:\PMIS
applicationUrl=/PMIS

Answer (score 0):

You can use Servant. Get it here http://servant.io/ just install it on your server and you are good to go

Answer (score 0):

Try this ASP.NET Web Site Administration Tool
http://sourceforge.net/projects/wsatudri/