# Open source ASP.net user membership manager?

Tags: asp.net-membership

Does anyone know of a good means to manage ASP.net membership parameters and accounts using an open source solution?

If not, can something be done that will allow the integrate security manager be accessed from a computer other than the server hosting the application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found this:

http://mywsat.codeplex.com/

"It allows you to manage membership users online once your site is deployed. It features complete administrative back-end functionality and designed to manage users, as well as admin pages for users to manage their own user data."

Answer (score 1):

Question is a bit old but we have just started working on an open source desktop application for managing users and roles. It is installed by ClickOnce and you point it at the web.config pf the website you want to administer.

http://aspnetmemberman.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

This answer may help you:

[Is there a ASP.NET web site administration tool in IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456921/is-there-a-asp-net-web-site-administration-tool-in-iis/843386#843386)